# Ошибка при загрузке фотографий через камеру (Android)

Tags: android, uri

Встретился с такой проблемой:

При загрузке картинки с галереи или фотографии с приложения камеры в приложение, сохраняется путь до этой картинки и производится её отображение в приложении.

Но, если версия андроид - 4.4.4 или 5, приложение вылетает именно после того, как я открыл приложение камеры и сделал фото, чтобы оно пошло в приложение. Эта ошибка наблюдается на 4х версиях андроид и на некоторых 5х(на Nexus5 - 6.0.1, SGS3 Cyanogen11 наблюдается ошибка, на LG G2 -5.0.2, sony z3c - 6.0.1, HTC - 4.3 не наблюдается). При выборе картинки с галереи (повторюсь) всё работает нормально.

Вызов интента:

```
boolean hasPermission = false;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED);
            }
            if (hasPermission) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((AppCompatActivity)getContext(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
            }else {
                ((CategoryGoodsActivity) getContext()).startActivityForResult(Utils.getPickImageIntent(getContext()), Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()) );
            }
```

Генерация интента:

```
public static Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context) {
    Intent chooserIntent = null;

    List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent);
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);

    if (intentList.size() > 0) {
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1), "Выберите");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    }

    return chooserIntent;
}
```

Получение картинки:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.e("sds", "requestCode="+requestCode+ "\nresultCode="+resultCode);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        String path = getPathFromCameraData(data, this);

        if (path != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("sds", path);
            switch (requestCode){
                case 1:
                    itemsComments.get(0).image1 = path;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    itemsComments.get(0).image2 = path;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    itemsComments.get(0).image3 = path;
                    break;
            }
            adapterComments.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

public String getPathFromCameraData(Intent data, Context context) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return picturePath;
    }else{
        return selectedImage.getPath();
    }
}
```

Лог при сбое:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {ru.diit.lefood/ru.diit.lefood.screens.food.CategoryGoodsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3389)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3432)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1253)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1420)
                                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:445)
                                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:404)
                                                                at ru.diit.lefood.screens.food.CategoryGoodsActivity.getPathFromCameraData(CategoryGoodsActivity.java:293)
                                                                at ru.diit.lefood.screens.food.CategoryGoodsActivity.onActivityResult(CategoryGoodsActivity.java:268)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3385)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3432) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1253) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566) 
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Скрины того, что я делаю:

По нажатию на скрепку выходят 2 пункта

[image: По нажатию на скрепку выходят 2 пункта]

Выбрали камеру и сделали снимок

[image: Выбрали камеру и сделали снимок]

При нажатии на кнопку принятия изображения вылетает

[image: При нажатии на кнопку принятия изображения]

В общем, жалуется в логе на эту строчку:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
```

которая находится в методе `getPathFromCameraData`:

```
public String getPathFromCameraData(Intent data, Context context) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return picturePath;
    }else{
        return selectedImage.getPath();
    }
}
```

Ругается, что переменная `selectedImage` нулевая. Делал дебаг этой строчки `Uri selectedImage = data.getData();` и data не пустая, думаю, что присвоение не работает или адрес на фото с камеры где-то теряется.

Не хочется извращаться, создавая пустой файл и позже присваивая ему фотографию, так как это работает с единичной фотографией, хотелось бы найти более простое решение.

В методе как раз закомментил извращенство с созданием файла:

```
public static Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context) {
    Intent chooserIntent = null;

    List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();


    //String imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +          "/picture.jpg";
    //File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
    //Uri picUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri

    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    //takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent);
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);

    if (intentList.size() > 0) {
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1), "Выберите");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    }

    return chooserIntent;
}
```

Манифест имеет:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) То что `data.getData()` возвращает `null` - это абсолютно нормально. Это означает лишь то,- что файл с полноразмерной фотографией небыл создан (нигде).
Обычно в таких случаях система возвращает thumbnail.
Обработать это можно например так:

```
if(data.getData()==null){
    bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
}else{
    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), data.getData());
}
```

2) Для того чтобы получить полноразмерное фото **обязятельно** нужно указывать **`EXTRA_OUTPUT`**. Об этом явно сказано в документации в разделе "Taking Photos Simply" -> ["Save the Full-size Photo"](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath)

Итого: нужно просто раскомментировать строчку с `EXTRA_OUTPUT`  :)

**UPD 14.09.2016 Создание временного файл.**
Для создания публичного файла в который может писать любое приложение (включая камеру) используйте:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
path.mkdirs();
File file = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");
```

Comment: это не сработало. Ошибку не показывает, но и на принятие фото не нажимается(последнее фото в вопросе, галочка для принятия фото просто нажимается и не реагирует). Левая и центральная кнопки при этом работают

Comment: Вы используете папку getExternalStorageDirectory() - для записи в неё нужно передавать камере дополнительные права (описано в той-же статье).  **Однако** если вы не хотите мучаться с передачей прав, то можно просто использовать папку  **getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()**.

Comment: а не знаете случайно, как можно удалить или изменить EXIF -данные такого файла? Когда я гружу свои же фото с сервера, они повёрнуты на 90 градусов. Я начал использовать библиотеку Glide вместо picasso, так как Glide поддерживает чтение EXIF-данных. И теперь эта библиотека поворачивает фотографии, кроме созданных мной(посредством этого ответа). Никогда раньше не взаимодействовал с exif-данными, а в гугле толком не нашёл информации по изменению этих данных, а конкретно про ориентацию. На англоязычном SO что-то, но реализацию не допетрил( Вы не сталкивались с этим?